# OpenCV not processing image in Unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, opencv

I'm working on a project that requires OpenCV within Unity, I've created a dll for my exported functions and everything is linked together properly.

When I run my code in Unity however, certain functions don't appear to do anything? And it will simply return the unaltered image back.

I pass images from Unity to OpenCV as a Color32 via this struct:

```
struct Color32
{
    uchar r;
    uchar g;
    uchar b;
    uchar a;
};
```

Then alter the image directly through pointers

```
void BlackAndWhite(Color32 **raw, int width, int height) 
{
    Mat frame(height, width, CV_8UC4, *raw);

    // Process image here
    cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
}
```

The final image in Unity should be altered as I've directly modified the image in the memory location, but in the case of this function that converts images to black and white there is no change and it outputs the image as though the function were never called.

The following function is linked exactly the same way as the one above, the only difference being the function body and it works as intended.

```
void processImage(Color32 **raw, int width, int height)
{
    Mat frame(height, width, CV_8UC4, *raw);

    // Process image here
    Mat edges;
    Canny(frame, edges, 50, 200);
    dilate(edges, edges, (5, 5));
    cvtColor(edges, edges, COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
    normalize(edges, edges, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
    multiply(frame, edges, frame);
}
```

This is how my code looks in Unity, the DLLs are exactly the same, if I modify the body of BlackAndWhite() to be the same as processImage() it will work as intended so it is definitely not an import issue or anything relating to the DLL.

```cs
public class OpenCV_Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("OpenCV_ImageProcessing")]
    public static extern void processImage(ref Color32[] raw, int width, int height);

    [DllImport("CrackDetection")]
    public static extern void BlackAndWhite(ref Color32[] raw, int width, int height);


    public RawImage CameraImage;
    private WebCamTexture webcam;
    private Texture2D cameraTexture;

    void Start()
    {
        webcam = new WebCamTexture();

        cameraTexture = new Texture2D(webcam.width, webcam.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        CameraImage.material.mainTexture = cameraTexture;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (webcam.isPlaying)
        {
            Color32[] rawImg = webcam.GetPixels32();
            cameraTexture = new Texture2D(webcam.width, webcam.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

            // Pass by reference, image is modified in place so no return required
            //processImage(ref rawImg, webcam.width, webcam.height); WORKS AS INTENDED
            BlackAndWhite(ref rawImg, webcam.width, webcam.height); // DOESNT WORK

            cameraTexture.SetPixels32(rawImg);
            cameraTexture.Apply();

            CameraImage.texture = cameraTexture;

            Debug.Log("Done!");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (webcam.isPlaying)
        {
            webcam.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            webcam.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm genuinely confused as to what is going on, the only thing I can think of is possibly incompatible Mat types? Or does OpenCV simply not modify an image if something is incorrect?

UPDATE: So I did a bit more testing and started writing the images to disk and the generated image files are properly processed, they are just not displayed in Unity for some reason.

Comment: `Color32 **raw` why two `*`? OpenCV expects continuous buffer and there is a patter for matrix where `Color32 **raw` is not a continues piece of memory. What is exactly passed by calling code?